# How can I get the state to change when passing the state and setState to component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple program here with React.js. What I am trying to do is click on a
name to display the age of the person. When I try to change the state without passing it to page1, it works just fine. But when I try to pass both the state and set state function, it craps out giving me errors I dont quite understand as I am still learning react so I thought i start with a simple example.

page1.js

```
import React from 'react';

const page1 = props => {
    //wrap in div
    //put in array form
    //make a higher order component
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 onClick = {() => props.showAge()}>Click to show age</h1>
            <h1>{props.age}</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default page1;
```

Here is my main container. The commented code at the bottom works. The (what I think is) equivalent of that when I try to pass it to page1, does not.

pages.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Page1 from './page1';
//import Page2 from './page2';
import './Pages.css';

class Pages extends Component {

  state = {
    age: "joe"
  }

  showAge() {
    this.setState({
      age: "25"
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Page1 
        age = {this.state.age}
        showAge = {this.showAge} />
        {/*<h1 onClick= {() => this.showAge()}}>Click to show age</h1>
        <h1>{this.state.age}</h1>*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pages;
```

Comment: Please share the error message with us.

Comment: Have you tried just doing `onClick={props.showAge}`? Without the parens at the end of the function name?

Comment: Have you tried put the state object into **constructor** function? We don't know the error, so we can't say exactly someting.

Comment: I have tried onClick = {props.showAge}. It doesnt read when I click.

Comment: I can post the error. This is when I leave it as {props.showAge()}. It Accets the click but when you click it, it gives you this error.

Comment: Where do you want to see the age? There is no info in the main component right now. Also, either bind your showState function or use an arrow function for that.

Comment: The error is to long to post. but you can reproduce it. Just leave the parenthesis. and everything renders to:

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Pages from './Pages';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Pages />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

Comment: I want to see age underneath where I click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need to trigger showAge in your page1 component as said in the comments. Use it like this:

```
<h1 onClick = {props.showAge}>Click to show age</h1>
```

Then, either bind your showAge function in the constructor or use arrow function instead:

```
showAge = () =>
    this.setState({
      age: "25"
    });
```